# NodeJS: Write file on windows that's only readable by the current user

Tags: node.js, windows, file-permissions, ntfs

Is there a straightforward way to write a file (e.g. with `fsPromises.writeFile(...)`) under NodeJS and Windows/NTFS, so that the written file only has read and write permission for the current user (and administrators), but not for other non-administrator users on the system? (In other words, a permission that corresponds to the POSIX mode `0600`.)

Note that POSIX permission flags in NodeJS are only implemented partially on Windows, or not at all. On a system with NodeJS 16.18.0 (where [S_IRUSR and S_IWUSR are defined](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/42757.)), the following:

```
const fsPromises = require('node:fs/promises');
const constants = require('node:constants');
fsPromises.writeFile(
  'c:\\hello.txt',
  'secret content',
  {mode: constants.S_IRUSR | constants.S_IWUSR}
);
```

...will result in a file that is readable by other non-administrator users on the system.